# Faster alternative to ShakesPeer?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've used ShakesPeer for it's clean and Mac-like interface. But the downloads are really slow. Is there a faster alternative to ShakesPeer?

Preferably having at least the same features as ShakesPeer itself if not more. Also preferable if the software follows the Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: Could you expand on the features for those not familiar with ShakesPeer?

Comment: Anything faster than ShakesPeer will do actually. It is about 10 times slower than anything else (on other platforms) that I've ever used.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried these but Jucy and EiskaltDC++ are two DirectConnect clients that work on mac.  However, neither appears to use a mac interface.

source: http://alternativeto.net/desktop/shakespeer/?sort=likes&platform=mac

Comment: Are they any faster?

Comment: someone else would have to comment on that... as I said I haven't tried them.  Just pointing you to some alternatives :)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever calavera pointed you at — also, try MLDonkey, NeoModus Direct Connect (DC original client!) and Valknut, they all have Mac versions.

Since I'm not a DC user, can't comment on speed =(